# window.open in a frame does not open PDF

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

While I was doing some testing in JSFiddle, which it executes codes in a frame, I found out that `window.open` does not open any PDF files when a link to a PDF file is passed.

```
window.open("https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf");
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/4ansfq9s/)

Is this a bug specific to Chrome (since I'm testing it on Chrome), or is it some kind of security measure that they put in? This only happens when `window.open` is executed in a frame.

Comment: `window.open()` requires user triggered event first

Comment: With document click will open https://jsfiddle.net/4ansfq9s/1/

Comment: @charlietfl The question isn't about that. Chrome does not need any user actions and it will happily open the tab for you. The question is about why there is no content after the tab is opened. (Your fiddle is the same, nothing shows up after the page is clicked. Maybe it's a bug specific to my system.)

Comment: OK...well when I go to demo in firefox does nothing...but works fine with an event

Comment: I would say this is more of a bug than some security measure.  I tested it in Firefox.  It works fine.  And in Chrome, the Network monitor does show the content (PDF) length, 182727 bytes.

Comment: @charlietfl Maybe I should add the Chrome tag to avoid confusion :)

Comment: For me in chrome on windows I get nothing happen without event...with event opens fine. Note that it opens in `chrome-extension://oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm/https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf`

Comment: @charlietfl Interesting. I'm using OSX and it's not working for me.

Comment: Not sure why it's opening in extension though and not proper url